# My user does not have administrative permission on Ubuntu Software Update

Tags: gnome, permissions, login, 20.04, gnome-software

I use Ubuntu 20.04. I can't get administrative permission to install programs in the Ubuntu Store, nor in Software & Updates. At the Ubuntu Store or GNOME Software, as soon as I send an application to install, information appears that I do not have permission to access. I realized that at the beginning there was information for me to login with my user. I typed in my username and password and nothing happened.

After some other system updates, my user was no longer able to install anything through the store. In "Software & Updates" I can't change anything there. No information is shown that the change I made worked and when I return, the changes I made have not been applied. The message can be viewed here.

[image]

In Settings I cannot unlock to manage my own user account or another one on the system.

[image]

I can manage the system using sudo in Gnome terminal and in any TTY without any problem which indicates that the bug may be from the desktop environment.

Comment: AFAIK GUI privilege escalation is handled by PolicyKit, and `pklocalauthority` uses membership of the `sudo` Unix group as the default for granting rights. Does you user obtain their sudo rights via group membership, or by an individual user entry in /etc/sudoers?

Comment: As stated before, my user gets administrative access using 'sudo' but in the desktop environment he has been presenting this problem described in my question.